# C time difference between two functions

Tags: c, performance

I have two simple code functions that compare two strings.

The strategy is to compare a short string with a long string sequentially.

For example,

```
string1 = "ABCDABCDEFGAHAD",
string2 = "ABCD"
```

then compare `string1` and `string2` by sliding `string2` until `string2`'s end is reached to `string1`'s end

Here are the functions that I used
First one is

```
void compare1(char* src , char* target , int src_size , int target_size , int* score){
   int i , j;
   for ( i = 0 ; i < src_size - target_size ; i++){
         for(j=0; j < target_size ; j++){
               if(src[i+j] == target[j]){
                    score[i]++;
               }else{
                     continue;
               }
         }
   }
}
```

and the second one is

```
void compare2(char* src , char* target , int src_size , int target_size , int* score){
       int i , j;
       char* dest = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*(target_size));
       for( i = 0 ; i < src_size - target_size ; i++){
            strncpy(dest,src,target_size);
            for( j = 0 ; j < src_size ; j++){
                if(dest[j] == target[j]){
                    score[i]++;
                }else{
                    continue;
                }
            }
        }
        free(dest);
    }
```

These two gave me different times, which are

```
8393.00 ms from compare1 
4415.00 ms from compare2
```

what makes this time difference?

the length of two strings are 1024*1024*10 and 128 with respect to src and target in function variable.

Comment: Your second function uses `malloc` and that could be costly, and it leaks memory since it does not call `free`

Comment: But the second is faster :)

Comment: Are you sure the 2nd if twice as fast? Do they perform the same job for sure, i.e. is the score the same? @BasileStarynkevitch Not only malloc, but also `strncpy`...

Comment: The functions don't do the same thing. The second version reads off the end of `dest`. You are comparing apples with oranges.

Comment: In my experience, 90% of all unexpected benchmarking results originate from incorrect benchmarking. It seems very unlikely that shuffling around 10Mb of data would take 8 seconds on any semi-modern computer. So how exactly do you measure this time and what is the target system?

Comment: Can you post your compiler options? Maybe you don't enable compiler optimizations. Theoretically f1 should be faster.

Comment: Moreover, if `( source_size (SS) >> target_size (TS) )`, then `compare1` is `O(SS)` while `compare2` is `O(SS^2)`, which makes it even more confusing. I guess it's reasonable if I correctly understand that `SS = 10^7` and `TS = 128`.

Comment: It is very hard to correctly benchmark functions when you are not aware about compiler optimizations. You might need to have a look at the assembler code...

Answer (score 3):

Your second function is wrong. It should copy from `src + i` not from `src`. Also the nested loop should be done for the `target_size` elements of `dest`, not for `src_size` as in your code. This results in:

```
void compare2(char* src , char* target , int src_size , int target_size , int* score){
       int i , j;
       char* dest = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*(target_size));
       for( i = 0 ; i < src_size - target_size ; i++){
            strncpy(dest,src + i,target_size);
            for( j = 0 ; j < target_size ; j++){
                if(dest[j] == target[j]){
                    score[i]++;
                }else{
                    continue;
                }
            }
        }
        free(dest);
    }
```

Remark 1: the `else continue;` is useless !
Remark 2: you can use `memcpy` to copy the string (since you know the length and don't use the terminal character `'\0'`).

Comment: It should also be worth mentioning that if OP is using `time` functions to generate these metrics, they aren't nearly as accurate as expected. It would be better to us an instrumented kernel and use a system profiler/debugger tool instead.